# How to use ExtUtils::MakeMaker to install data in a custom directory

Tags: linux, perl, makefile

I need to install my main script (as executable) in **/usr/bin** (depends on the INSTALL_BASE). That part is done.

The next one is to install into the directory **/usr/share/project_name/data** options.txt, this one is hard for me, see my codes:

Manifest file:

```
data/options.txt
script/joel-perl
Makefile.PL
```

## Makefile.PL

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile (
    NAME => 'joelperl',
    VERSION_FROM => 'script/joel-perl',
     PREREQ_PM => {
        'Switch' => 0
     },
    EXE_FILES => ['script/joel-perl'],
    PM => {
        'data/options.txt' => '$(INSTALL_BASE)/share/project_name/data'
    }
);
```

When running:

```
perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE="/usr"
make
```

I get "**ERROR: Can't create '/usr/share/project_name'**", so my question is:

How to add/copy files to an especific place, like in my case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [File::ShareDir::Install](http://metacpan.org/pod/File::ShareDir::Install) module:

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;
use File::ShareDir::Install;

install_share 'data';

WriteMakefile(...);

package MY;
use File::ShareDir::Install qw(postamble);
```

Comment: Note how `package MY` is literally `MY`. It is not supposed to be your package name!